# Why there are two ".tt" files generated when I use database first approach in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the picture below,two tt files are generated when I used DB First approach in entity framework. Just curious to know, what is the roles and responsibilities of each file.

[image]

Comment: The first one generates the DbContext and the second one generates your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the files and select "View Code". You'll see one creates the DbContext, the other generates the class files for your entities.

Comment: Then what is the difference between DbContext and ObjectContext. Would you please explain to me.